# Error showing "The variable 'uLS1' appears to change size on every loop iteration. consider preallocating for speed."

Tags: matlab

```
% 3. Calculation of strain energy density
% CALCULATION OF STRAIN-ENERGY-DENSITY FOR EACH LOAD CASE
% u=1/2*sigma*epsilon

for p = 1:N_ele
    uLS1(p) = 1/2*(sigma_1(p,2:7)*epsilon_1(p,2:7)');
    uLS2(p) = 1/2*(sigma_2(p,2:7)*epsilon_2(p,2:7)');
    uLS3(p) = 1/2*(sigma_3(p,2:7)*epsilon_3(p,2:7)');
end
% AVERAGE OF ALL LOAD CASES
sed(:,a) = (uLS1' + uLS2' + uLS3')/3;       %11 ...    line
```

**Error on command window:**

> "Unrecognized function or variable '`uLS1`'."
>
> Error in `main_file` (line 86)
> `sed(:,a) = (uLS1' + uLS2' + uLS3')/3;`

Comment: It seems like you mix 2 sources of error. The first when you execute the script (Unrecognised function or variable error), and the second one that appears when the script is analysed for performance enhancement (loop iteration). Both are totally unrelated. Fix the first one by declaring uLS1 before using it, like uLS1 = [];. The second error is just a warning.

Comment: after using this uLS1 = zeros(1:N_ele); , uLS2 = zeros(1:N_ele);, uLS3 = zeros(1:N_ele); preallocation error is not coming but error still showing in sed(:,a) = (uLS1' + uLS2' + uLS3')/3;   - "Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side."    How do I prelallocate this sed as there is no loop here?

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the error:** The variable `sed` must have N_ele rows such that `size(sed,1) = N_ele`. If the number `N_ele` changes with every iteration `a`, then you can use a cell instead an array, i.e., `sed{a} =  (uLS1' + uLS2' + uLS3')/3;`.

**Regarding the warning:** Preallocate the arrays `uLS1`, `uLS2`, and `uLS3` before the for-loop when you know the size they will have, i.e.,

```
uLS1 = zeros(1, N_ele);
uLS2 = zeros(1, N_ele);
uLS3 = zeros(1, N_ele);
```

If you don't know their sizes in advance, you have the choice to ignore Matlab's warning and proceed as is.